# What is the largest perfect square that divides $2014^3-2013^3+2012^3-2011^3+\ldots+2^3-1^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divisibility

I've tried this but didn't get the answer :
Let $S=2014^3-2013^3+2012^3-2011^3+\ldots+2^3-1^3$

Using $n^3-(n-1)^3 = 3n^2-3n+1$,
\begin{align}
S &= 3(2014^2)-3(2014)+1+3(2012^2)-3(2012)+1+\ldots+3(2^2)-3(2)+1
\\&= 3\left ( 2014(2013)+2012(2011)+2010(2009)+ \ldots+2(1)  \right ) + 1(1007)
\\&= 3\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{1007}2n(2n-1) \right )+1007\\
=& \left ( \sum_{n=1}^{1007}4n^2-\sum_{n=1}^{1007}2n \right )+1007
\\=&\frac{12(1007)(1008)(2015)}{6}-\frac{2(1007)(1008)(3)}{2}+1007
\end{align}
This is divisible by $1007$ but not by $1007^2$ which is the correct answer. Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: $$\sum_{k = 1}^{2n} (-1)^k k^3 = 2\sum_{k = 1}^n (2k)^3 - \sum_{k = 1}^{2n} k^3 = 16 \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac{(2n)^2(2n+1)^2}{4} = n^2\bigl(4(n+1)^2 - (2n+1)^2\bigr) = n^2(4n+3).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}&\frac{12(1007)(1008)(2015)}{6}-\frac{2(1007)(1008)(3)}{2}+1007
\\&=1007\left(\frac{12(1008)(2015)}{6}-\frac{2(1008)(3)}{2}+ 1\right)
\\&=1007\left(2(1008)(2015)-(1008)(3)+ 1\right)
\\&=1007\left(2(1007+1)(2015)-(1007+1)(3)+ 1\right)
\\&=1007\left(1007(2(2015)-3)+2(2015)-3+ 1\right)
\\&=1007\left(1007(2(2015)-3)+2(2015)-2\right)
\\&=1007\left(1007(2(2015)-3)+2(2014)\right)
\\&=1007\left(1007(2(2015)-3)+4(1007)\right)
\\&=1007^2(2(2015)-3+4)
\\&=1007^2(4031)\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew I was this close! Is it possible to factorize this without using a calculator ?

Answer (score 2):

In general you obtain, for $n^3-(n-1)^3+\cdots + 2^3-1^3$ and $n$ even the formula
$$
3\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} 2k(2k-1)\right)+\frac{n}{2}.
$$
Now it is easier to see that this is divisible by $(\frac{n}{2})^2$; and you can test this first for $n=2,4,6,\ldots$ before dealing with $n=2014$. In fact, your computation is correct, except for the last step, where you did not realize how to split of the factor $(\frac{n}{2})^2$. Working with general $n$, you do not need a calculator.

Comment: Thanks, isn't the summation from k=1 to n/2 ?

Comment: Oh sure, I wasn't finished with the formula yet, sorry.

Comment: Is it a property that it is divisible by $\left (\frac{n}{2} \right )^2 $?

Comment: Yes, it is. Take $n=4$. Then the formula gives $44$, which is divisible by $(4/2)^2=4$. Now assume it holds for $n$, and show it for $n+2$.

Comment: Is there also a general formula if n is odd ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have given one already. You only need to continue with $n^3-(n-1)^3=3n^2-3n+1$, which is true for all $n$. Divisibility, however, is something different then.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2m}(-1)^n n^3&=\sum_{n=1}^m (2n)^3-(2n-1)^3\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m 12n^2-6n+1\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m 24 \binom n2+6\binom n1+1\\
&=24\binom {m+1}3+6\binom {m+1}2+m\\
&=m\; \big[\;4(m+1)(m-1)+3(m+1)+1\;\big]\\
&=m^2(4m+3)\\
\end{align}$$
which is divisible by $m^2$.

Putting $m=1007$ gives the answer required.